# Разность hash-сумм после нарезки и склеивания файла

Tags: gzip, hashcode

Есть файл, который требуется разобрать и сжать(gzip) по частям и сохранить данные в некотором файле, что было мной проделано путём нехитрых махинаций. Затем развернуть сжатый файл в оригинальный, путём обратных преобразований. 
Всё бы ничего, целостность данных сохраняется, однако hash-суммы этих файлов разнятся.

Подскажите:

1. От чего зависит hash-сумма файла?
2. Почему два, казалось бы, абсолютно одинаковых файла имеют разные хеши?
3. Можно ли каким-либо образом присвоить файлу hash-сумму, или передать её?

UPD^^

Добавлю что файл многократно открывается и дописывается до тех пор, пока не будет копией оригинала.

Comment: Так в итоге, если вы второй файл постоянно дописываете, у вас файлы одинаковые или разные?

Comment: Хеш-сумма для файла обычно зависит от его содержимого (побайтового). И если два файла одинаовые, то и хеш (любой) должен быть одинаковый.

Но может файлы текстовые? и отличаются переводном строк? тогда для Вас они будут идентичны.